# Remover impressora e driver

Tags: c#, .net, impressora, driver

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
private void btnDeletar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string nomeImpressora = null;
    if(cmbImpressoras.SelectedIndex != -1)
        nomeImpressora = cmbImpressoras.SelectedItem.ToString();
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Selecione uma Impressora");

    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
    scope.Connect();
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    ManagementObjectCollection printers = search.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)
    {
        string printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();

        if (printerName.Equals(nomeImpressora.ToLower()))
        {
            try
            {
                DriverImpressora(printer["DriverName"].ToString());
                printer.Delete();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Impossível remover impressora!");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora a dúvida:

Creio que seja somente removida a impressora, mas, o drive não, se não remove o drive, usando a classe Win32_PrinterDriver é possivel remover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já sabe a resposta para a primeira dúvida.

A segunda é possível, você está no caminho certo, mas não é tão simples. Não sei exatamente como fazer mas parece que há uma solução aproximada do que você quer em uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18253679/221800). Está em VBS mas acho que ali é possível ver todos os passos necessários para executar por completo a tarefa. Note que é necessário deletar outros componentes do sistema.

Talvez a parte mais relevante esteja na resposta mas veja o todo para não fazer o serviço pela metade.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrinterDriver"
For Each driver In objWMIService.ExecQuery(qry)
  If driver.Name = "..." Then driver.Delete_
Next
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Printer.vb).

Comment: Obrigado, já me deu um bom caminho, editei a pergunta e coloquei o código que to usando para remover, porém está dando um erro de generic failure.

Comment: A edição normalmente é feita quando você vai melhor a mesma pergunta adicionando informações que ajudem naquela pergunta. Se você vai fazer outra pergunta não deve usar a edição se não as respostas dadas se tornam inválidas.

Comment: Ok, voltei para a pergunta original!